# Magento 2 @escapeNotVerified

Tags: magento2, template

I see a lot of occurences of this comment `/* @escapeNotVerified */` in the template files for Magento2.
Does it have a special meaning?
Is there any use for this?

Examples:

- https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1/app/code/Magento/Catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml#L23
- https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1/app/code/Magento/Catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/image_with_borders.phtml#L10
- https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1/app/code/Magento/Catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/gallery.phtml#L12
- I could go on for a few pages here.

Comment: Hey...Why the downvote? I'm not allowed to ask questions?

Answer (score 108, accepted):

This tag is used by static tests. Any potentially unsafe output must be marked with either `@escapeNotVerified` or `@noEscape` to pass tests, the latter means that this particular usage has been checked and is safe.

In the future releases all occurrences of `@escapeNotVerified` will be verified and either marked with `@noEscape` or escaped with one of these methods:

- `\Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock::escapeHtml`
- `\Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock::escapeUrl`
- `\Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock::escapeXssInUrl`
- `\Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock::escapeQuote`

Also note that some output is considered safe and should not be marked with such annotations:

- Enclosed in single quotes
- Enclosed in double quotes but without variables
- Type casting to bool, int
- Method calls which contain 'html' in their names, like `getTitleHtml`, are also expected to output escaped HTML

Comment: Greats answer @Alex

Comment: Good Ans +1 @Alex  :)

Comment: It helps +1 @Alex

Comment: At current pace, the replacement will be done approximately 2026 :D

Answer (score 27):

I find it in devdocs of Magento2

**Static Test**

To improve security against XSS injections, a static test `XssPhtmlTemplateTest.php` is added to dev\tests\static\testsuite\Magento\Test\Php.

This static test finds all echo calls in PHTML-templates and determines if it is properly escaped or not.

It covers the following cases:

- `/* @noEscape */` before output. Output doesn’t require escaping. Test is green.
- `/* @escapeNotVerified */` before output. Output escaping is not checked and should be verified. Test is green.

**Read the Magento Docs** at
[2.0](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-security.html)
or
[2.1](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-security.html)