# Magento 2 @escapeNotVerified vs. escaping methods in custom code

Tags: magento2, template, security

I want to combine two topics and ask someone more expirenced about tag `@escapeNotVerified`. I have read topics [about this tag](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92963/magento-2-escapenotverified) and also about [different escaping methods](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/143273/using-different-escaping-methods).

Although I am not sure - if I write some custom code in templates and I will use some of escaping methods - should I match content with tag `@escapeNotVerified`? I understand, that my content is already escaped and I don't have to. Is this tag some temporal magento team members annotation to correct in future?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you should not mark any code as @escapeNotVerified, it's temporary mark that will be removed in future.

Comment: What about `@noEscape`?

Comment: @noEscape marks places where escaping is not needed